# Как изменить текст всплывающего предупреждения required pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

В хроме так:
[image: предупреждение]

В разных браузерах текста предупреждений отличаются

Comment: хороший вопрос ! интересно увидеть ответ на него

Comment: "Вид и содержание сообщения зависит от браузера и меняться пользователем не может." https://webref.ru/html/input/required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно задать свое сообщение, в зависимости от типа ошибки. 
 В каждом `input` содержится специальный объект `validity`, включающий в себя список булевых значений(true или false), характеризующих ту или иную проверку на валидность. 
Список свойств этого объекта с описанием на русском языке: https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/95-form-validation-techniques

```js
$('input').on('input invalid', function() {
    this.setCustomValidity('')
    if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
      this.setCustomValidity("Нет значения")
    }
    if (this.validity.typeMismatch) {
      this.setCustomValidity("Не соответствует типу")
    }
    if (this.validity.patternMismatch) {
      this.setCustomValidity("Не соответствует паттерну")
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="email" placeholder="email"/>
  <input type="text" required placeholder="обязательный" />
  <input type="tel" pattern="[^A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+$" placeholder="без букв" required>
  <button>тест</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 текст валидации вы изменить не можете, но для pattern текст тайтла записать можно нативными способами:

example1:

```
<input type="text" value="" pattern="(\d|(\d,\d{0,2}))" title="YOUR_WARNING_TEXT" >
```

example2:

```
<form action="somefile.php">
    <input
        type="text"
        name="username"
        placeholder="Username"
        pattern="[a-z]{1,15}"
        title="Username should only contain lowercase letters. e.g. john">
</form>
```

Comment: можно через js:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818629/247349

Answer (score -1):

А не проще подключить js-валидацию и выводить ошибки каким-нибудь Popovers?
Вот простой пример:    See the Pen https://codepen.io/CognitoForms/pen/mxvdGV/'>Form Validation Styles: After by Cognito Forms (https://codepen.io/CognitoForms'>@CognitoForms) on https://codepen.io'>CodePen.

Comment: Не разобрался как просто ссылку кинуть с codepen